# Including NaN on time series plot from xlsread MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, nan, xlsread

I use xlsread to read a xlsx file

```
t = xlsread('CurrentA3.xlsx','Sheet1','A2:A5709');
mag = xlsread('CurrentA3.xlsx','Sheet1','B2:B5709');
dir = xlsread('CurrentA3.xlsx','Sheet1','C2:C5709');
u = xlsread('CurrentA3.xlsx','Sheet1','D2:D5709');
v = xlsread('CurrentA3.xlsx','Sheet1','E2:E5709');
```

The first 111 datas from the Excel file is NaN, and when I try to plot into time series it skipped the first 111 NaN datas and straight to the 112th data and so on. But all the NaN datas after that are includes in the plot. How do I fix that so the first 111 datas are also includes in the plot?

I already tried this

```
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(mag,'color','#00FA9A');
ylim([0 115])
set(gca,'YTick',([0 30 60 90 115]),'YTickLabel',{'0','30','60','90','115'});
xlim([0 5708]);
set(gca,'XTick',([1 687 1418 1980 2711 3441 4172 4902 5708]),...
    'XTickLabel',{'14/11/2000','01/10/2002','01/10/2004','01/10/2006','01/10/2008','01/10/2010','01/10/2012','01/10/2014','16/12/2016'});
grid on
```

and I expected the first 111 NaN datas was going to be included to the plot but it didn't.

Comment: What do you mean, included? NaN means “not a number”. There is no position along the y axis that means “not a number”, so there is no way to include those points. You could plot little x-es on the x axis for the points that are NaN, or you could in some other way note that those samples are NaN, but MATLAB won’t plot them because it can’t.